# Spring boot 1.3.x MultipartFile.transferTo null after migration from 1.2.x

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am facing error MultipartFile error for one day after having upgrade from Spring Boot 1.2.7 to 1.3.1.

What I notice is that the default is now Jetty 9.2 and no more Tomcat 8. Everything was fine until I tried to write an uploaded file using `MultipartFile.transferTo(File file)` method..

`MultipartFile.transferTo()` method is calling an implementation of `javax.servlet.http.Part` Which is implemented this way for tomcat 8

```java
@Override
public void write(String fileName) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    if (!file.isAbsolute()) {
        file = new File(location, fileName);
    }
    try {
        fileItem.write(file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
```

and this way for jetty 9.2

```java
    public void write(String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        if (_file == null)
        {
            _temporary = false;

            //part data is only in the ByteArrayOutputStream and never been written to disk
            _file = new File (_tmpDir, fileName);

            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
            try
            {
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(_file));
                _bout.writeTo(bos);
                bos.flush();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (bos != null)
                    bos.close();
                _bout = null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //the part data is already written to a temporary file, just rename it
            _temporary = false;

            File f = new File(_tmpDir, fileName);
            if (_file.renameTo(f))
                _file = f;
        }
    }
```

What's wrong with the Jetty implementation is that is waiting for file name `File.getName()` and not the absolute path name `File.getPath()` which is provided by the call of `StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.transferTo(File file)`

```java
    @Override
    public void transferTo(File dest) throws IOException, IllegalStateException {
        this.part.write(dest.getPath());
    }
```

Is this a bug ? Note that this occurs since I have upgraded from spring boot 1.2.7 to 1.3.1. The default was Tomcat and now it is Jetty...

Comment: The default container is still Tomcat (starter-web depends on starter-tomcat). You must have something else that's putting Jetty on the classpath.

Comment: probably neo4j dependency I guess...

Comment: There's a fair bit of missing information in this question, such as what your `MultiPartConfig` is for that endpoint that receives the file.  The servlet spec defaults are that the container decides if you don't specify the behavior.  Each container will operate a little bit differently if you don't define it yourself.

Comment: See also https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12650 with the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the javadoc for [`javax.servlet.http.Part.write(String filename)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html#write-java.lang.String-) the `filename` parameter is ...

> The file is created relative to the location as specified in the
>   MultipartConfig

In the code you referenced in Jetty 9.2, namely this ...

jetty-9.2.14.v20151106 - [`MultiPartInputStreamParser.write(String fileName)`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.14.v20151106/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/MultiPartInputStreamParser.java#L245-L280)

You'll see that there's 2 possible code paths it takes, the first is the "in memory" path, and the second is "file on disk" approach.

In both cases, when you specify a filename to `Part.write(String)` that name is relative to your `MultiPartConfig.location` (a configuration of which you haven't detailed in your question).

The implementation of `MultiPartInputStreamParser` has a `_tmpDir` [which is configured from the webapp's `MultiPartConfig.location`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.14.v20151106/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/MultiPartInputStreamParser.java#L448-L464).

If you want this to behave properly, would highly recommend you define a `MultiPartConfig.location` that is appropriate for your application, instead of relying on the container to pick one.

The Tomcat approach of allowing absolute filenames in `Part.write(String)` is actually not allowed in the servlet spec (mainly as its a security issue that can be used to cause havoc on a system)

Comment: Thanks @Joakim, that is correct ! Thanks for your clarification, I miss this point !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, at the moment if you want to get rid of this error you can switch back to Tomcat instead of Jetty.

Put tomcat into your dependencies:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
```

And declare tomcat as container:

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
}
```